# Installing TensorFlow with Pip Python on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow

Last month they released tensor-flow comparability with windows. Looking at the docs I've installed python 3.6 and run

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

but it doesn't find it and therefore doesn't install it.

```
could not find a version that satisfies the requirements tensorflow-gpu(from versions)
```

Am I missing something basic? How can I fix or circumvent this?

Comment: `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A stable release of Python 3.6 for Windows became available on 12/23/2016, and we have not yet built TensorFlow packages for that version. (We will look into doing this after the holidays.) For now, your best options are:

1. Downgrade to Python 3.5 (64-bit version), which the pre-built packages support.
2. Try [building TensorFlow from source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake).

Answer (score 11):

Here is what i did to get tensorflow working with windows.

[Download](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.0/python-3.5.0-amd64.exe) python 3.5.0 (64 bit from [Python Releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/getit/windows/))
Install it and check python version by running below command in cmd:

```
python --version
Python 3.5.0
```

Then run below command to upgrade pip to latest

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now install tensorflow using pip

```
pip install tensorflow
```

That's it you have installed tensorflow on windows. Below image shows what happens when you type above commands
[image]

[Example](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#test_the_tensorflow_installation) to verify tensorflow is working.

```
$ python
...
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to install Python 3.5 not 3.6. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: thanks bro it wrork i just uninstall the 3.6 and install the 3.5

Answer (score 0):

pip3 install tensorflow==tensorflow_version

Available tensorflow versions: (0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)